# Not able to call node from command prompt

Tags: windows, node.js, command, prompt

I have tried setting [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) in System path but I am still unable to call it from the command prompt in Windows 7

I have to set `SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%` every time I want to call it from the command prompt.

Comment: the installer should do that for you. Did you get any errors while installing?

Answer (score 0):

set node.js and npm path in environment variables.if its not set as u do for java

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm trying to list the possible reasons, please check each, and if any try to fix it

- The `path/to/node` you are proving is *wrong*, instead try adding to path as follow

  `set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Program Files\nodejs`
  OR for 32bit architecture 
  `set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Program Files(x86)\nodejs`
- There may be some error so download the latest NODE according to your architecture from [here](http://nodejs.org/download/).
- If still not working please post more details/error so that we can get idea of what actually is going on.